# Do I have to use 'location' and 'startDate' for UserComments?

Tags: schema.org

I am using the schema.org type [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) in a website. The page allows users to comment on the articles. In Article is mentioned that comments can be marked with the [`UserComments`](http://schema.org/UserComments) type. I did that and it worked great for a long time.

Some days ago Google (Webmaster Tools) started to complain about errors in my markup. 
They want me to add the properties `location` and `startDate` to each comment.

Currently I only use the the properties `creator`, `commentTime` and `commentText`.

Why is there a need of adding the above mentioned properties? I don't have a idea what the `location` and `startDate` could be for a simple users comment.

(Is this maybe just a Google trick to collect more data?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the failure messages in Googles Webmaster Tools are gone. Looks like Google has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google is complaining *where*? The following example is valid according to Microdata and schema.org (and the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.de/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) doesn’t show any warnings/errors):

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Article name</h1>
  <article itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">
    <p itemprop="commentText">Comment text</p>
  </article>
</article>
```

(I also tested a snippet containing `creator` and `commentTime`: no warnings either.)

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention that. Google is complaining about the missing properties in the Google Webmaster Tools.